# How does AccessResult::neutral() work?

Tags: 8

I have seen in code:

```
AccessResult::neutral()
AccessResult::allowed()
AccessResult::forbidden()
```

`allowed()` and `forbidden()` are pretty obvious, but how does `neutral()` work?

I have been debugging and sometimes `neutral()` allow access and sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

“Neutral” basically means “I don’t care” in this context.

Returning it means you’re saying that your code has no opinion on whether access should be granted or not, and that other methods/modules should make the decision.

Comment: Thanks @Clive !

Comment: As this is one of the first result on google, although old: I've just discovered after some painful search that `AccessResult::neutral()` isn't coherent and depends on the type of access check is being evaluating. E.g. in case of Route access check, `AccessResult::neutral()` actually **denies** the access - see [the issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2991698#comment-14009628) for more detailed discussion about.